# Set background color for XWPFParagraph

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I want to change the background color for paragraph but I cannot find the way on how to do it. I could find only how to highlight words. I want my text to look like in [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot is not really clear. It could show multiple different things. But as you are talking about `Word` paragraph, I suspect it shows a paragraph having a border and a shading.

Following code creates a `Word` document having a paragraph having having a border and a shading. The border settings can be achieved using methods of `XWPFParagraph`. The shading settings are not provided there until now. So methods and classes of underlying `ooxml-schemas` are needed.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordParagraphBackground {

 private static void setParagraphShading(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String rgb) {
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() == null) paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr();
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getShd() != null) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().unsetShd();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewShd();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getShd().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STShd.CLEAR);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getShd().setColor("auto");
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getShd().setFill(rgb);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Folollowing paragraph with border and shading:");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();  
  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
  paragraph.setBorderTop(Borders.SINGLE);
  paragraph.setBorderRight(Borders.SINGLE);
  paragraph.setBorderBottom(Borders.SINGLE);

  setParagraphShading(paragraph, "BFBFBF");

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, ");
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.TEXT_WRAPPING);
  run.setText("sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.");
  run.addBreak(BreakType.TEXT_WRAPPING);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordParagraphBackground.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```